# How to convert "DATASET POLYDATA" vtk file to "DATASET STRUCTURED_GRID"?

Tags: vtk

I have a **vtk** file with header like:

```
# vtk DataFile Version 3.0
vtk output
ASCII
DATASET POLYDATA
POINTS 1000 float
```

now I need to convert it to a **structured vtk** file with header like:

```
# vtk DataFile Version 2.0
VTK from Matlab
ASCII
DATASET STRUCTURED_GRID
DIMENSIONS 32 32 1
POINTS 1000 float
```

is there a program or script to convert between these two types?

Comment: Is your data indeed structured? Keep in mind, converting vtkPolyData to vtkStructuredGrid is more than just a file conversion. In fact, your data should be capable of being represented as a structured grid.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer thank you for responding. Yes, it is. it has ellipsoid like shape. Indeed, it is cardiac wall in the left ventricle denoted by few points.

Comment: OK, I'm not quite sure that it is possible to store such an ellipsoid manifold into `vtkStructuredGrid` class or not. What do you want to do with this `vtkStructuredGrid` that is not possible to do with `vtkPolyData`?

Comment: @AloneProgrammer I have an executable file which simply works with structured grids (samples contained in it work well using this kind of vtk). I am wondering if I can find a script or so to change my unstructured data into structured grid.